# www.nanog.com resolves to localhost

Tags: nslookup

By mistake typed www.nanog.com while trying to visit http://www.nanog.org/ and landed to localhost. The url www.nanog.com resolves to localhost somehow, even with google's DNS server.

Just for curiosity sake, does any one have any idea why www.nanog.com resolves to localhost?

> C:\Windows\System32>nslookup www.nanog.com 8.8.8.8
>   Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
>   Address:  8.8.8.8
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
>   Name:    www.nanog.com
>   Address:  127.0.0.1
>
> C:\Windows\System32>nslookup www.nonexistingwebsite.com 8.8.8.8
>   Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
>   Address:  8.8.8.8
>
> *** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find www.nonexistingwebsite.com: Non-existent domain
>
> C:\Windows\System32>

Comment: DNS admins can set the records up however they like. Perhaps the admin wanted to set www.nanog.com to 127.0.0.1 for testing purposes. In a past job I set `quit` to resolve to a CNAME of `type.exit.you.fool` because `nslookup` in interactive mode doesn't accept `quit` as a command to quit the program, and that was just a pointed reminder.

Comment: @Faisal: you were trying to browse www.nanog.org but you looked at www.nanog.com, which resolves to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the owner of the domain name set it up that way.

Answer (score 2):

It resolves to localhost because the DNS admin for nanog.com domain created an A record pointing to 127.0.0.1